# What is "fliveck"?

Tags: word-meaning

I've heard the following in an episode of a series and, while I understand the **implied** meaning of the word, I'd like to know more details about it (such as origin, usage, frequency etc.). I haven't been able to locate any resources on the net that referred to it though.

> I wanted to clone a sheep, but I needed to start with something simpler.
>   Which he is, because his brain is **fliveck**.

In fact, I wasn't even sure how to spell it so the spelling I'm using is provided by [this link](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=the-simpsons&episode=s25e18) and I claim no responsibility that it's, in fact, right. Feel free to correct, should you see it fit.

Answer (score 4):

That's not actually a word in English, and was made up for that episode of *The Simpsons*. The character in question has a habit of using made-up sciency-sounding words; the word is intentionally nonsense, and the implied meaning is the only meaning it has.

Comment: That's a disappointment... Not to question your answer (and I definitely see how your reasoning makes sense with respect to said character) but I was hoping that the word had **some**, if yet far fetched, reference to or origin in something. Something like, for instance, *fly* being an organism with very weak brainpower and *veck* being an archaic word for not being able to achieve, making the epithet "*one that can't even achieve the brainpower of a fly*". But it's fully possible that in this particular case, it's just a made-up nonsense word...